# How do visual studio stored multibyte - like chinese words

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, unicode, utf-8

Recently I learnt about Unicode, and download its code chart. And test on visual studio for different language support.

I use a chinese word for an example, it's 我.
Chinese Charcter 我, Unicode number is U-6211.

I test how visual studio stored this word, and find out the string is CED2, as example.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  unsigned char *p="我";
  while(*p)
  {
    fprintf(stdout, "%2X ", (unsigned int)*p);
    p++;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

the I got on screen is CE D2, I know how UTF-8, UTF-16, UCS-2 coded. But I can't find match for this. I suppose it is something called DBCS.

MY QUESTION is, how to translate unicode to this DBCS seemed?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Is the question about how the source is stored? Or how the compiler bundles that string in the binary?

Comment: yes, it is. if I dont know how it stored, it's really hard to store some chars.

Answer (score 0):

Haha, question solved by myself...

I am using Visual Studio at the Chinese-Simplified Environment.

Charcter set is using DBCS with GBK mode...yes this special un-known GBK

http://www.unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/VENDORS/MICSFT/WindowsBestFit/bestfit936.txt

This is the Code Chart, nothing further.